# И снова прямая речь

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Раньше было слово «внедрение», потом пошли «инновации», но вот есть предложение от «Тяжпромкомплекта»: «Приходите, поможем».

Правильно ли я оформила прямую речь? Может ли такое предложение произноситься без восклицательной интонации? И также - можно ли здесь обойтись без тире? (Приходите - поможем)

Answer (score 1):

Всё оформлено правильно.

Желательно оставить: «Приходите, поможем». Для тире нужна другая форма глагола: "придете - поможем".

Comment: Оформлено правильно. С этим никто не спорит. Вот только у меня не показывает кавычки и тире. И вашем тексте тоже. Удивительно!!!

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

У вас после двоеточия стоят кавычки? Если нет, то надо поставить кавычки. Восклицательная интонация зависит  от автора. Тире факультативно. См. Интонационное тире. Справочник-практикум.Стр.135. Д.Э. Розенталь.

Comment: Да, конечно кавычки.

Comment: У вас после двоеточия одна запятая.Исправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Исправила. О какой запятой вы говорите?

Comment: Перед словом "приходите".

Comment: А где там нужна запятая?!

Comment: Вот именно, что не нужна. А у вас стоит.

Comment: Раньше было слово «внедрение», потом пошли «инновации», но вот есть предложение от «Тяжпромкомплекта»: «Приходите, поможем».

Где запятая перед "приходите"? Там двоеточие и открывающие кавычки.

Comment: У меня показывает, что там запятая.Да еще и лишние символы? У вас что, не показывает?